# configuring serial port from kernel space

Tags: linux-device-driver

How to configure the serial port in kernel module. I am doing this in init module function. same configuration is working in userpsace. I am using the below code to configure the serial port.

```
mm_segment_t oldfs;

oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
fp = filp_open("/dev/ttyS0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
tty = (struct tty_struct *)fp->private_data;
setting the required configuration(tty->termios)
set_fs(oldfs);
```

Comment: could you tell what is your goal? I'm quite sure kernel already has a serial port driver for you to use, look in `include/linux/serial_core.h` for functions to use it and maybe `include/linux/serio.h` if you want to write a driver for device using serial port

Comment: thanks for your reply. my intention is to write a kernel module which will read from and write to serial port at 115200 baudrate for every gpio interrupt. For that i want to set baudrate and some tty parameters from my kernel module. thanks again

Comment: hussain, do you get any progress on this function?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all functions of serial port operations are implemented by `drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c`. If you want to do it differently then provide your own functions for `uart_ops` from `include/linux/serial_core.h`

```
struct uart_ops {
        unsigned int    (*tx_empty)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*set_mctrl)(struct uart_port *, unsigned int mctrl);
        unsigned int    (*get_mctrl)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*stop_tx)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*start_tx)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*send_xchar)(struct uart_port *, char ch);
        void            (*stop_rx)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*enable_ms)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*break_ctl)(struct uart_port *, int ctl);
        int             (*startup)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*shutdown)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*flush_buffer)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*set_termios)(struct uart_port *, struct ktermios *new,
                                       struct ktermios *old);
        void            (*set_ldisc)(struct uart_port *, int new);
        void            (*pm)(struct uart_port *, unsigned int state,
                              unsigned int oldstate);
        int             (*set_wake)(struct uart_port *, unsigned int state);
        const char *    (*type)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*release_port)(struct uart_port *);
        int             (*request_port)(struct uart_port *);
        void            (*config_port)(struct uart_port *, int);
        int             (*verify_port)(struct uart_port *, struct serial_struct *);
        int             (*ioctl)(struct uart_port *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
#ifdef CONFIG_CONSOLE_POLL
        void    (*poll_put_char)(struct uart_port *, unsigned char);
        int             (*poll_get_char)(struct uart_port *);
#endif
};
```

In your case, you need to implement set_termios function. Also, look at `uart_get_divisor()` to know how to set baud rate.