# Is there any solution to set baud rate, line discipline etc., by only using our kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I wrote a kernel module for a touch screen monitor and earlier I used inputattach (written in userspace) to open serial port, set baud rate, control flags, line discipline etc.

But now I want to implement the functionalities of inputattach directly in our driver as we don't want to trigger our driver from an userspace program i.e inputattch.

But I cant able to set c_ispeed, c_ospeed, c_cflag, c_iflag, line discipline, etc., in kernel space.

Is there any solution to set baud rate, line discipline etc., by only using our kernel module?

Comment: You can't. the `termios` and `ioctl` functions or syscalls are for user land code. And you probably should not! Keep the userland `inputattach` thing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Starynkevitch is there any alternate way to set baudrate from kernelspace?

Comment: i read it is possible to configure serial ports in kernel space by using serial_core.c (ref:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342644/configuring-serial-port-from-kernel-space?rq=1]). if it is so, can anybody tell how it can be done?

Comment: Even if possible, I recommend avoiding kernel-space if you can.

Comment: can i know why it is not recommended to configure serial port in kernel space?

Comment: Also asked on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/498478/